# The Yacc rule I wanted doesn't reduce

Tags: c, yacc, lex

I have a problem where my rule can't reduce. First, I want to write a Yacc rule in order to detect a statement:

```
STUDENT_T* pSearch=pHead;
```

So I wrote the rule as below:

```
struct_initialize: IDENTIFIER '*' IDENTIFIER '=' IDENTIFIER ';';
```

Then I put the `struct_initialize` on rule as below:

```
struct_declaration
: struct_initialize
| specifier_qualifier_list ';'  /* for anonymous struct/union */ {printf("29\n");}
| specifier_qualifier_list struct_declarator_list ';' {printf("30\n");}
| static_assert_declaration {printf("31\n");}
;
```

My full Yacc file is below:

```
%token  IDENTIFIER I_CONSTANT F_CONSTANT STRING_LITERAL FUNC_NAME SIZEOF
%token  PTR_OP INC_OP DEC_OP LEFT_OP RIGHT_OP LE_OP GE_OP EQ_OP NE_OP
%token  AND_OP OR_OP MUL_ASSIGN DIV_ASSIGN MOD_ASSIGN ADD_ASSIGN
%token  SUB_ASSIGN LEFT_ASSIGN RIGHT_ASSIGN AND_ASSIGN
%token  XOR_ASSIGN OR_ASSIGN
%token  TYPEDEF_NAME ENUMERATION_CONSTANT

%token  TYPEDEF EXTERN STATIC AUTO REGISTER INLINE
%token  CONST RESTRICT VOLATILE
%token  BOOL CHAR SHORT INT LONG SIGNED UNSIGNED FLOAT DOUBLE VOID
%token  COMPLEX IMAGINARY
%token  STRUCT UNION ENUM ELLIPSIS

%token  CASE DEFAULT IF ELSE SWITCH WHILE DO FOR GOTO CONTINUE BREAK RETURN

%token  ALIGNAS ALIGNOF ATOMIC GENERIC NORETURN STATIC_ASSERT THREAD_LOCAL

%token INCLUDE


%start translation_unit
%{

    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>
    extern FILE* yyin;
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *s);

%}
%union{
    char* a;
    char* b;
}

/*%type <a>IDENTIFIER
*%type <a>SIGNED UNSIGNED
*%type <a>INT CHAR DOUBLE FLOAT LONG SHORT
*%type <b>EXTERN STATIC AUTO REGISTER*/

%%

include
: '#' INCLUDE '<' IDENTIFIER '.' IDENTIFIER '>'
| '#' INCLUDE  STRING_LITERAL
;

struct_initialize
: IDENTIFIER '*' IDENTIFIER '=' IDENTIFIER ';'
;



primary_expression
: IDENTIFIER    {printf("1\n");}
| constant
| string
| '(' expression ')'
| generic_selection
;

constant
: I_CONSTANT        /* includes character_constant */ {printf("2\n");}
| F_CONSTANT
| ENUMERATION_CONSTANT  /* after it has been defined as such */
;

enumeration_constant        /* before it has been defined as such */
: IDENTIFIER {printf("3\n");}
;

string
: STRING_LITERAL
| FUNC_NAME
;

generic_selection
: GENERIC '(' assignment_expression ',' generic_assoc_list ')'
;

generic_assoc_list
: generic_association
| generic_assoc_list ',' generic_association
;

generic_association
: type_name ':' assignment_expression
| DEFAULT ':' assignment_expression
;

postfix_expression
: primary_expression  {printf("59\n");}
| postfix_expression '[' expression ']' {printf("60\n");}
| postfix_expression '(' ')' {printf("61\n");}
| postfix_expression '(' argument_expression_list ')' {printf("62\n");}
| postfix_expression '.' IDENTIFIER {printf("63\n");}
| postfix_expression PTR_OP IDENTIFIER {printf("64\n");}
| postfix_expression INC_OP
| postfix_expression DEC_OP
| '(' type_name ')' '{' initializer_list '}' {printf("65\n");}
| '(' type_name ')' '{' initializer_list ',' '}' {printf("66\n");}
;

argument_expression_list
: assignment_expression
| argument_expression_list ',' assignment_expression
;

unary_expression
: postfix_expression {printf("67\n");}
| INC_OP unary_expression
| DEC_OP unary_expression
| unary_operator cast_expression {printf("71\n");}
| SIZEOF unary_expression
| SIZEOF '(' type_name ')'
| ALIGNOF '(' type_name ')'
;

unary_operator
: '&'
| '*'
| '+'
| '-'
| '~'
| '!'
;

cast_expression
: unary_expression {printf("68\n");}
| '(' type_name ')' cast_expression {printf("69\n");}
;

multiplicative_expression
: cast_expression {printf("70\n");}
| multiplicative_expression '*' cast_expression
| multiplicative_expression '/' cast_expression
| multiplicative_expression '%' cast_expression
;

additive_expression
: multiplicative_expression {printf("71\n");}
| additive_expression '+' multiplicative_expression
| additive_expression '-' multiplicative_expression
;

shift_expression
: additive_expression {printf("72\n");}
| shift_expression LEFT_OP additive_expression
| shift_expression RIGHT_OP additive_expression
;

relational_expression
: shift_expression {printf("73\n");}
| relational_expression '<' shift_expression
| relational_expression '>' shift_expression
| relational_expression LE_OP shift_expression
| relational_expression GE_OP shift_expression
;

equality_expression
: relational_expression {printf("74\n");}
| equality_expression EQ_OP relational_expression
| equality_expression NE_OP relational_expression
;

and_expression
: equality_expression {printf("75\n");}
| and_expression '&' equality_expression
;

exclusive_or_expression
: and_expression {printf("76\n");}
| exclusive_or_expression '^' and_expression
;

inclusive_or_expression
: exclusive_or_expression {printf("77\n");}
| inclusive_or_expression '|' exclusive_or_expression
;

logical_and_expression
: inclusive_or_expression {printf("78\n");}
| logical_and_expression AND_OP inclusive_or_expression
;

logical_or_expression
: logical_and_expression {printf("79\n");}
| logical_or_expression OR_OP logical_and_expression
;

conditional_expression
: logical_or_expression {printf("80\n");}
| logical_or_expression '?' expression ':' conditional_expression
;

assignment_expression
: conditional_expression {printf("81\n");}
| unary_expression assignment_operator assignment_expression {printf("69\n");}
;

assignment_operator
: '='
| MUL_ASSIGN
| DIV_ASSIGN
| MOD_ASSIGN
| ADD_ASSIGN
| SUB_ASSIGN
| LEFT_ASSIGN
| RIGHT_ASSIGN
| AND_ASSIGN
| XOR_ASSIGN
| OR_ASSIGN
;

expression
: assignment_expression {printf("82\n");}
| expression ',' assignment_expression
;

constant_expression
: conditional_expression    /* with constraints */
;

declaration
: declaration_specifiers ';'    /* no rule need*/ {printf("4\n");}
| declaration_specifiers init_declarator_list ';' /* int a;*/ {printf("5\n");}
| static_assert_declaration {printf("6\n");}
;

declaration_specifiers
: storage_class_specifier declaration    {printf("7\n");}
| storage_class_specifier               {printf("8\n");}
| type_specifier declaration_specifiers {printf("9\n");}
| type_specifier {printf("10\n");}
| type_qualifier declaration_specifiers{printf("11\n");}
| type_qualifier {printf("12\n");}
| function_specifier declaration_specifiers {printf("13\n");}
| function_specifier {printf("14\n");}
| alignment_specifier declaration_specifiers {printf("15\n");}
| alignment_specifier {printf("16\n");}
;

init_declarator_list
: init_declarator {printf("17\n");}
| init_declarator_list ',' init_declarator {printf("18\n");}
;

init_declarator
: declarator '=' initializer {printf("19\n");}
| declarator {printf("20\n");}
;

storage_class_specifier
: TYPEDEF   /* identifiers must be flagged as TYPEDEF_NAME */ {printf("21\n");}
| EXTERN
| STATIC
| THREAD_LOCAL
| AUTO
| REGISTER
;

type_specifier
: VOID
| CHAR
| SHORT
| INT
| LONG
| FLOAT
| DOUBLE
| SIGNED
| UNSIGNED
| BOOL
| COMPLEX
| IMAGINARY     /* non-mandated extension */
| atomic_type_specifier
| struct_or_union_specifier
| enum_specifier
| TYPEDEF_NAME      /* after it has been defined as such */ {printf("22\n");}
;



struct_or_union_specifier
: struct_or_union '{' struct_declaration_list '}' {printf("23\n");}
| struct_or_union IDENTIFIER '{' struct_declaration_list '}' {printf("24\n");}
| struct_or_union IDENTIFIER {printf("25\n");}
;

struct_or_union
: STRUCT
| UNION
;

struct_declaration_list
: struct_declaration {printf("26\n");}
| struct_declaration_list struct_declaration {printf("27\n");}
;

struct_declaration
: struct_initialize
| specifier_qualifier_list ';'  /* for anonymous struct/union */ {printf("29\n");}
| specifier_qualifier_list struct_declarator_list ';' {printf("30\n");}
| static_assert_declaration {printf("31\n");}
;

specifier_qualifier_list
: type_specifier specifier_qualifier_list {printf("32\n");}
| type_specifier {printf("33\n");}
| type_qualifier specifier_qualifier_list {printf("34\n");}
| type_qualifier {printf("35\n");}
;

struct_declarator_list
: struct_declarator {printf("36\n");}
| struct_declarator_list ',' struct_declarator {printf("37\n");}
;

struct_declarator
: ':' constant_expression {printf("38\n");}
| declarator ':' constant_expression {printf("39\n");}
| declarator {printf("40\n");}
;

enum_specifier
: ENUM '{' enumerator_list '}'
| ENUM '{' enumerator_list ',' '}'
| ENUM IDENTIFIER '{' enumerator_list '}'
| ENUM IDENTIFIER '{' enumerator_list ',' '}'
| ENUM IDENTIFIER
;

enumerator_list
: enumerator
| enumerator_list ',' enumerator
;

enumerator  /* identifiers must be flagged as ENUMERATION_CONSTANT */
: enumeration_constant '=' constant_expression
| enumeration_constant
;

atomic_type_specifier
: ATOMIC '(' type_name ')'
;

type_qualifier
: CONST
| RESTRICT
| VOLATILE
| ATOMIC
;

function_specifier
: INLINE
| NORETURN
;

alignment_specifier
: ALIGNAS '(' type_name ')'
| ALIGNAS '(' constant_expression ')'
;

declarator
: pointer direct_declarator
| direct_declarator
;

direct_declarator
: IDENTIFIER  {printf("41\n");}
| '(' declarator ')' {printf("42\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' ']' {printf("43\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' '*' ']' {printf("44\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' STATIC type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']' {printf("45\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' STATIC assignment_expression ']' {printf("46\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list '*' ']'
| direct_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list STATIC assignment_expression ']'
| direct_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']'
| direct_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list ']' {printf("47\n");}
| direct_declarator '[' assignment_expression ']' {printf("48\n");}
| direct_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')' {printf("49\n");}
| direct_declarator '(' ')' {printf("50\n");}
| direct_declarator '(' identifier_list ')' {printf("51\n");}
;

pointer
: '*' type_qualifier_list pointer
| '*' type_qualifier_list
| '*' pointer
| '*'
;

type_qualifier_list
: type_qualifier {printf("52\n");}
| type_qualifier_list type_qualifier {printf("53\n");}
;


parameter_type_list
: parameter_list ',' ELLIPSIS
| parameter_list
;

parameter_list
: parameter_declaration
| parameter_list ',' parameter_declaration
;

parameter_declaration
: declaration_specifiers declarator
| declaration_specifiers abstract_declarator
| declaration_specifiers
;

identifier_list
: IDENTIFIER
| identifier_list ',' IDENTIFIER
;

type_name
: specifier_qualifier_list abstract_declarator
| specifier_qualifier_list
;

abstract_declarator
: pointer direct_abstract_declarator
| pointer
| direct_abstract_declarator
;

direct_abstract_declarator
: '(' abstract_declarator ')'
| '[' ']'
| '[' '*' ']'
| '[' STATIC type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']'
| '[' STATIC assignment_expression ']'
| '[' type_qualifier_list STATIC assignment_expression ']'
| '[' type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']'
| '[' type_qualifier_list ']'
| '[' assignment_expression ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' '*' ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' STATIC type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' STATIC assignment_expression ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list assignment_expression ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list STATIC assignment_expression ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' type_qualifier_list ']'
| direct_abstract_declarator '[' assignment_expression ']'
| '(' ')'
| '(' parameter_type_list ')'
| direct_abstract_declarator '(' ')'
| direct_abstract_declarator '(' parameter_type_list ')'
;

initializer
: '{' initializer_list '}'
| '{' initializer_list ',' '}'
| assignment_expression {printf("83\n");}
;

initializer_list
: designation initializer
| initializer
| initializer_list ',' designation initializer
| initializer_list ',' initializer
;

designation
: designator_list '=' {printf("54\n");}
;

designator_list
: designator {printf("55\n");}
| designator_list designator {printf("56\n");}
;

designator
: '[' constant_expression ']'
| '.' IDENTIFIER
;

static_assert_declaration
: STATIC_ASSERT '(' constant_expression ',' STRING_LITERAL ')' ';'
;

statement
: labeled_statement
| compound_statement
| expression_statement
| selection_statement
| iteration_statement
| jump_statement
;

labeled_statement
: IDENTIFIER ':' statement
| CASE constant_expression ':' statement
| DEFAULT ':' statement
;

compound_statement
: '{' '}'
| '{'  block_item_list '}'
;

block_item_list
: block_item
| block_item_list block_item
;

block_item
: declaration
| statement
;

expression_statement
: ';'
| expression ';'
;

selection_statement
: IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
| IF '(' expression ')' statement
| SWITCH '(' expression ')' statement
;

iteration_statement
: WHILE '(' expression ')' statement
| DO statement WHILE '(' expression ')' ';'
| FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement ')' statement
| FOR '(' expression_statement expression_statement expression ')' statement
| FOR '(' declaration expression_statement ')' statement
| FOR '(' declaration expression_statement expression ')' statement
;

jump_statement
: GOTO IDENTIFIER ';'
| CONTINUE ';'
| BREAK ';'
| RETURN ';'
| RETURN expression ';'
;

translation_unit
: external_declaration
| translation_unit external_declaration
;

external_declaration
: function_definition
| declaration
| include    /********/
;

function_definition
: declaration_specifiers declarator declaration_list compound_statement
| declaration_specifiers declarator compound_statement
;

declaration_list
: declaration  {printf("57\n");}
| declaration_list declaration {printf("58\n");}
;

%%
#include <stdio.h>

void yyerror(const char *s)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "*** %s\n", s);
}
void parse(FILE* fileInput)
{
    yyin= fileInput;
    while(feof(yyin)==0)
    {
        yyparse();// To read file, while() and yyparse() is necessary because we need to read until the content is run out
    }
}
```

This is corresponding Lex code:

```
%e  1019
%p  2807
%n  371
%k  284
%a  1213
%o  1117

Q   \"
O   [0-7]
D   [0-9]
NZ  [1-9]
L   [a-zA-Z_]
A   [a-zA-Z_0-9]
H   [a-fA-F0-9]
HP  (0[xX])
E   ([Ee][+-]?{D}+)
P   ([Pp][+-]?{D}+)
FS  (f|F|l|L)
IS  (((u|U)(l|L|ll|LL)?)|((l|L|ll|LL)(u|U)?))
CP  (u|U|L)
SP  (u8|u|U|L)
ES  (\\(['"\?\\abfnrtv]|[0-7]{1,3}|x[a-fA-F0-9]+))
WS  [ \t\v\n\f]

%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "y.tab.h"

    extern void yyerror(const char *);  /* prints grammar violation message */

    extern int sym_type(const char *);  /* returns type from symbol table */

    #define sym_type(identifier) IDENTIFIER /* with no symbol table, fake it */

    static void comment(void);
    static int check_type(void);
%}

%%


"/*"                                    { comment(); }
"//".*                                    { /* consume //-comment */ }

"include"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INCLUDE); }
"void"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(VOID); }
"int"                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INT); } /* Data Type*/
"long"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(LONG); }
"char"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CHAR); }
"short"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SHORT); }
"signed"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SIGNED); }
"double"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DOUBLE); }
"unsigned"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(UNSIGNED); }
"float"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(FLOAT); }


"auto"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(AUTO); } /*Storage Class*/
"extern"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(EXTERN); }
"register"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(REGISTER); }
"static"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(STATIC); }


"const"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CONST); } /*Type Qualifier*/
"restrict"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(RESTRICT); }
"volatile"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(VOLATILE); }
"_Atomic"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ATOMIC; }


"break"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(BREAK); }
"case"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CASE); }

"continue"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(CONTINUE); }
"default"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DEFAULT); }
"do"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(DO); }
"else"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(ELSE); }
"enum"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(ENUM); }

"for"                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(FOR); }
"goto"                  { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(GOTO); }
"if"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(IF); }
"inline"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(INLINE); }


"return"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(RETURN); }
"sizeof"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SIZEOF); }

"struct"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(STRUCT); }
"switch"                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(SWITCH); }
"typedef"               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(TYPEDEF); }
"union"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(UNION); }



"while"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return(WHILE); }
"_Alignas"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ALIGNAS; }
"_Alignof"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ALIGNOF; }

"_Bool"                 { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return BOOL; }
"_Complex"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return COMPLEX; }
"_Generic"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return GENERIC; }
"_Imaginary"            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return IMAGINARY; }
"_Noreturn"             { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return NORETURN; }
"_Static_assert"        { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return STATIC_ASSERT; }
"_Thread_local"         { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return THREAD_LOCAL; }
"__func__"              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return FUNC_NAME; }

{Q}                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return'"'; }
"..."                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ELLIPSIS; }
">>="                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return RIGHT_ASSIGN; }
"<<="                   { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LEFT_ASSIGN; }
"+="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ADD_ASSIGN; }
"-="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return SUB_ASSIGN; }
"*="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return MUL_ASSIGN; }
"/="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return DIV_ASSIGN; }
"%="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return MOD_ASSIGN; }
"&="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return AND_ASSIGN; }
"^="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return XOR_ASSIGN; }
"|="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return OR_ASSIGN; }
">>"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return RIGHT_OP; }
"<<"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LEFT_OP; }
"++"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return INC_OP; }
"--"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return DEC_OP; }
"->"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return PTR_OP; }
"&&"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return AND_OP; }
"||"                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return OR_OP; }
"<="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return LE_OP; }
">="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return GE_OP; }
"=="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return EQ_OP; }
"!="                    { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return NE_OP; }
";"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ';'; }
("{"|"<%")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '{'; }
("}"|"%>")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '}'; }
","                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ','; }
":"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ':'; }
"="                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '='; }
"("                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '('; }
")"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ')'; }
("["|"<:")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '['; }
("]"|":>")              { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return ']'; }
"."                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '.'; }
"&"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '&'; }
"!"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '!'; }
"~"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '~'; }
"-"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '-'; }
"+"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '+'; }
"*"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '*'; }
"/"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '/'; }
"%"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '%'; }
"<"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '<'; }
">"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '>'; }
"^"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '^'; }
"|"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '|'; }
"?"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '?'; }
"#"                     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return '#'; }

{L}{A}*                 {  return check_type(); }

{HP}{H}+{IS}?               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
{NZ}{D}*{IS}?               { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
"0"{O}*{IS}?                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return I_CONSTANT; }
{CP}?"'"([^'\\\n]|{ES})+"'"     { return I_CONSTANT; } /**/

{D}+{E}{FS}?                { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}*"."{D}+{E}?{FS}?        { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{D}+"."{E}?{FS}?            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+{P}{FS}?            { yylval.a=strdup(yytext);return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}*"."{H}+{P}{FS}?     { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }
{HP}{H}+"."{P}{FS}?         { yylval.a=strdup(yytext); return F_CONSTANT; }

({SP}?\"([^"\\\n]|{ES})*\"{WS}*)+   { return STRING_LITERAL; }


{WS}+                   { /* whitespace separates tokens */ }

.                   { /* discard bad characters */ }

%%

int yywrap(void)        /* called at end of input */
{
    return 1;           /* terminate now */
}

static void comment(void)
{
    int c;

    while ((c = input()) != 0)
    if (c == '*')
    {
        printf("1: %d\n",c);
        while ((c = input()) == '*')
        ;
        printf("2: %d\n",c);
        if (c == '/')
        return;
        if (c == 0)
        printf("3: %d\n",c);
        break;
    }
    yyerror("unterminated comment");
}

static int check_type(void)
{
    switch (sym_type(yytext))
    {
        case TYPEDEF_NAME:                /* previously defined */
            {
                printf("TYPEDEF_NAME\n");
            return TYPEDEF_NAME;
            }
        case ENUMERATION_CONSTANT:        /* previously defined */
            {
            printf("ENUMERATION\n");
            return ENUMERATION_CONSTANT;
            }
        default:                          /* includes undefined */ /*This is when do normal declaration such as int a=3; in this case it return a*/
            {
            printf("IDENTIFIER\n");
            yylval.a=strdup(yytext);
            return IDENTIFIER;
            }
    }
}
```

When it read to the statement: `STUDENT_T* pSearch=pHead;`The output is:

```
--accepting rule at line 156 ("STUDENT_T")
IDENTIFIER
--accepting rule at line 146 ("*")
1
59
67
68
70
--accepting rule at line 173 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 156 ("pSearch")
IDENTIFIER
1
59
--accepting rule at line 135 ("=")
67
68
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
*** syntax error
```

**Note that I used `printf` with string literal as number 1-80 for debugging in the Yacc file.**
Could you please tell me where I went wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Text consisting of only

> ```
> STUDENT_T* pSearch=pHead;
> ```

is not valid in the grammar you've presented, as it is being tokenized.

Your lexer is matching `STUDENT_T` as the first token, which is fine.  It is classifying it as an `IDENTIFIER`, which seems to be reasonable in context.  But at that point you're dead: there is no text complying with your grammar that starts with an `IDENTIFIER`.  The fact that your `struct_initialize` production can match your token sequence does not help, because even if the parser reduced the entire input to that symbol, there is no way to reduce it the rest of the way to the `translation_unit` start symbol.

For what it's worth, *my* `yacc` (byacc 1.9) emits a parser that errors out as soon as it sees an `IDENTIFIER` as the first token, and so does my `bison` (v2.7).  I find it a bit surprising that your `yacc` gives you a parser that does more work before recognizing that there's no hope, if indeed it's operating on the input you specified.  Any way around, though, I see no reason to think the parser is producing incorrect results.

---

Looking more deeply at your grammar, the only place a `struct_initialize` can appear is where it can serve as a `struct_declaration`.  That is used only as part or all of a `struct_declaration_list`, which is the contents of a structure or union declaration.  Indeed, this text is accepted by a parser built from your grammar:

```
struct { STUDENT_T* pSearch=pHead; };
```

and a bit of extra instrumentation shows that the parser uses your production in doing so.